# Lua Dot After Integer

Tags: lua

I have a script that return a double value.  When it return a integer value I need to add a dot after integer. Is there any clean way to do that.

Example

```
return 3/2  --> 1.5 (its ok )
return 8/2 --> 4 (its not ok. I need to print 4. (4 with dot). )
return 8/2--> 4.   (This is what I want)
```

Ps. Im not a native english speaker. If I wrote sth funny sorry about that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an HTML block of code to a string (concat) in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235165/adding-an-html-block-of-code-to-a-string-concat-in-lua)

Comment: @helvete how is your comment related to this question?

Comment: @Piglet : The OP clearly wants to concatenate the division result w/ string `.`

Comment: @helvete Thanks but i think this is whole other thing. I can't even understand situation there. Anyway my problem already solved. Thx your concern.

Comment: @HyouZou Good to hear that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return 1 + .0
```

will convert an integer `1` to a float `1.0`

Usually you would divide by a float if you want a float result.

```
return 8/2.0
```

I don't see why you would want to print that number with a decimal point if there are no decimals. That doesn't make too much sense.
If you insist to do so you should use `string.format` to format your string.

```
if math.type(n) == "integer" then
  print(string.format("%d.", n))
elseif math.type(n) == "float" then
  print(string.format("%f", n))
end
```

Comment: math.type doesn't work on my lua( I think its about the version that I use) but thanks to your tip I solved my problem with  using % operator instead of math.type.

About the why I insist decimal point,

Printed values are using in another system. That system interpret values without decimal point as micron instead of milimeter. Its cause huge trouble for me. 

Thanks for help and have a nice day

Comment: if you'd just use 1.0 instead of 1. things would be much easier. then you can simply format all numbers with %f with the desired precision and wouldn't have to distinguish between integers and floats

Comment: Some cases file sizes are matter. Old machines has little memory like 500kb. So I need to minimum amount character as possible in the output file. So as a technical personel with no programming ability, I try to make optimal solution in main script. Have a nice day.